# Imagem sobreposta e responsiva

Tags: html, css, html5, layout-responsivo

estou ainda na fase inicial de Web Design e tenho a seguinte dúvida: Eu devo sobrepor a imagem 1 exatamente no espaço "em branco" da imagem 2. Porém ambas devem ser responsivas. Tentei o código abaixo. Agradeceria demais a ajuda

[Clique aqui para ver a imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Upcl.jpg)

HTML

```
<body>

    <div>
        <div> <img id="mainPic" src="pic/wowburger1.jpg" alt="wowburger1"> 
         <img id="orderbutton" src="pic/order.jpg" alt="orderonline"> </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

CSSS

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1600px;
    min-width: 500px;
}

#mainPic {
    width: 100%; 
    max-height: 750px; 
  
    position: relative; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px;
}

#orderbutton {
    width: 10%;
    max-height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute; top: 20%; left:20%; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Então, para colocar o botão order por cima da imagem principal, você pode utilizar o CSS para posicionar as imagens. Primeiro, é necessário definir um elemento pai para as duas imagens e setar sua posição como relativa. Depois, você pode posicionar a imagem do botão utilizando as propriedades position e z-index

Pra posicionar a imagem do botão em relação à imagem principal, você pode utilizar as propriedades top, left, right e bottom e ajustar de acordo com o resultado que vc quer.

### Algo assim:

**HTML;**

```
<body>
<div class="image-wrapper">
    <img id="mainPic" src="pic/wowburger1.jpg" alt="wowburger1"> 
    <img id="orderbutton" src="pic/order.jpg" alt="orderonline">
</div>
```

---

**CSS;**

```
 body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1600px;
    min-width: 500px;
}

.image-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

#mainPic {
    width: 100%; 
    max-height: 750px;
}

#orderbutton {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 20%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

---

Não esquece de ajustar as dimensões das imagens pra que elas fiquem do tamanho certo, com essas dicas vc pode deixar sua página com um visual bacana e responsivo

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Muito obrigado parceiro, segui suas instruções e deu certo aqui :)